# Percent Change Formula Gives -% unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate a % change from X to Y. I have taken a look here https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-change-calculator.php and can see it can be calculated as:

> (v2 - v1) / v1 * 100

So I have applied this in both PySpark and standard Python:

```
#formula: (v2 - v1) / v1 * 100

data = [(1, 19360, 49387), (1, 4189, -3039)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = ["id", "february_sales", "january_sales"])

df.show()

+---+--------------+-------------+
| id|february_sales|january_sales|
+---+--------------+-------------+
|  1|         19360|        49387|
|  1|          4189|        -3039|
+---+--------------+-------------+

df = df.withColumn('percent_change', (sf.col('february_sales') - sf.col('january_sales')) / sf.col('january_sales') * 100)

df.show()

+---+--------------+-------------+------------------+
| id|february_sales|january_sales|    percent_change|
+---+--------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1|         19360|        49387|-60.79940065199344|
|  1|          4189|        -3039|-237.8413951957881|
+---+--------------+-------------+------------------+

feb = 4189
jan = -3039

print((feb - jan)/ jan * 100)

-237.8413951957881
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but when I plug v1 = -3039, v2 = 4189 into % change calculators (https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage-change, https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-change-calculator.php), I get + 237%. How come in Python / PySpark I am getting -237%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second link you shared the denominator is converted to absolute value, which is missing in your code. To replicate the same check the code below.

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import abs
df = df.withColumn('percent_change', (df.february_sales - df.january_sales) / abs(df.january_sales) * 100)
df.show()
```